# Нужно убрать отступ между круглой картинкой и бордером

Tags: css

Есть квадратная кратинка, я закруглил ее при помощи такого кода:

```
    .userAvatar {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    
}

.userInfo .userAvatar img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.2vw solid #B3BBD0;
}
```

и задал бордер вокруг картинки. Но почему-то получаю небольшой отступ между картинкой и бордером, хотя ни маргина ни паддинга там нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема наблюдается только в Google Chrome. Видимо какие-то дефолтные настройки брузера.

Comment: Стоит добавить это [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1329790/edit), а не писать ответ к нему.

Comment: Это ответ. Тк это проблема не css стилей, а самой версии браузера.